# Yubikey PIV not working without OTP

Tags: ssh, fedora, certificates, yubikey, otp

I just started using a Yubikey to do SSH logins by following [this](https://developers.yubico.com/PIV/Guides/SSH_with_PIV_and_PKCS11.html) guide.

It works fine - but only as long as the Yubikey is able to do OTP. After a few accidental touches on the key spewing a random string into places I don't want it I figured I could just disable OTP as I'm only using PIV.

Cert/key is there and working:

```
$ ykman --version
YubiKey Manager (ykman) version: 5.1.0
$ cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 38 (Thirty Eight)
$ ykman piv info
PIV version:              5.4.3
PIN tries remaining:      3/3
Management key algorithm: TDES
CHUID: No data available
CCC:   No data available
Slot 9A (AUTHENTICATION):
  Algorithm:   ECCP256
  Subject DN:  CN=SSH key
  Issuer DN:   CN=SSH key
  Serial:      14009452700000000000
  Fingerprint: 1fa375971a89c6f82f3b73218f717cb1d031fbd61c94965qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
  Not before:  2023-03-10T10:02:12
  Not after:   2024-03-09T10:02:12
```

I can disable OTP:

```
$ ykman config usb --list
OTP
FIDO U2F
FIDO2
OATH
PIV
OpenPGP

$ ykman config usb --disable OTP
USB configuration changes:
  Disable OTP
  The YubiKey will reboot
Proceed? [y/N]: y

$ ykman config usb --list
FIDO U2F
FIDO2
OATH
PIV
OpenPGP
```

But after doing that, SSH no longer works, and I'm prompted for a password instead of the expected key-based login

I can enable OTP again:

```
$ ykman config usb --enable OTP
USB configuration changes:
  Enable OTP
  The YubiKey will reboot
Proceed? [y/N]: y
```

Which restores SSH functionality.

Why must OTP be enabled for PIV to work?

Comment: If I reboot the machine after disabling OTP or if I use YubiKey Manager from windows to disable it it seem to work as intended. Feels like a bug in ykman (maybe specifically in conjuction with Fedora 38).